# ng-repeat not working inside of modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a shop page that is meant to pop up a modal when clicking on a "More Details" button that offers the "name" and "description" from a JSON file. So far, I've only been able to get the name and description for the first item of the JSON array, regardless of which button I click. HTML looks like so:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row clear-fix">
        <div ng-repeat="product in shop" class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                    <img ng-repeat="image in product.images" ng-src='{{image.full}}' />
                </div>
                <h2>{{product.price | currency}}</h2>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">More Details</button>

                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">{{product.name}}</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>{{product.description}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: One problem is that you generates many `modals` with same id.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai can you tell me what you're referring to? I'm not seeing the many modals that you are talking about.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm having a hard time getting the angular-ui-bootstrap version to work. Do I have to create a new function in that case to open the modal?

Comment: yes you would, using `ng-click`